# What's the difference when adding a private modifier to arguments in a Kotlin's constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm not sure about the difference between the following two constructors written in Kotlin

```
class ConcreteItem(val title: String) : Item() {

}
```

and

```
class ConcreteItem(private val title: String) : Item() {
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is the "private" modifier before the title field. How will it affect the scope of the title field?

Comment: `private` will make it, well private to the instance, and val will have a public getter - tip : look at the decompiled code.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Not only is it superfluous to mark "private" as code, you also failed to do that correctly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code:

```kotlin
class ConcreteItem(val title: String) : Item() {
}
```

is a shortcut for:

```kotlin
class ConcreteItem(title: String) : Item() {
    val title: String = title
}
```

where lack of explicit access modifier for `val title` implies `public`:

```kotlin
class ConcreteItem(title: String) : Item() {
    public val title: String = title
}
```

Similarly, the following code:

```kotlin
class ConcreteItem(private val title: String) : Item() {
}
```

is a shortcut for:

```kotlin
class ConcreteItem(title: String) : Item() {
    private val title: String = title
}
```

Taking that in account, the difference between two declarations is simply declaring public property vs private property.

Comment: very clean explanation, I like it

Comment: This isn't actually true. Both examples in the OP create private members. The difference is that `val title: String` will create a getter and `private val title: String` wont

Answer (score 4):

if the `private` modifier is applied, then a public "getter" won't be synthesized whereby other classes can interrogate the value of "title". otherwise will be.

Answer (score -2):

You almost always want your constructor arguments available to all the code in the class. This would be the idiomatic way to make a private member variable from a constructor parameter.

```
class ConcreteItem(private val title: String) {}
```

If you similar to Java, that means:

```
class ConcreteItem {
    private final String title;

    public ConcreteItem(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `private` modifier has nothing to do with the availability of the property "to all the code in the class". moreover, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Don't focus on "to all the code in the class". I just said the reason why they place the `private` there.

Comment: `This would be the idiomatic way to make a private member variable from a constructor parameter.` This is my answer. However, look at my example code.